# How to customise two select tags different colors?

Tags: html, css, select

I have two select tags in my webpage. However I come to customize both of them different colors. Any suggestions on how I can do that?

This is my code below.

```css
select {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  width: 80%;
  overflow-y: auto;
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px;
  background-color: #4472C4;
}

select option {
  border: none;
  margin-top: -1px;
  /* Prevent double borders */
  padding: 12px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 1.5vw;
  color: black;
  display: block
}

select option :hover:not(.header) {
  background-color: aliceblue;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<td width=20% style="background-color: #4472C4">
  <label>
    <h2>Our Recommended Favorites</h2>
    <select size=9 id="myList" class="list-content" onchange="setPicture();">
    </select>
  </label>
</td>
<td width=40%>
  <label>
    <select size=3 id="myList-1" class="list-content"></select>
  </label>
</td>
```

Comment: You shouldn't use tables for layout, but this is a very basic css question so perhaps you need to do a few tutorials first to learn about css classes and how to use them?

Answer (score 1):

You can style them using the css selector for id's `#`
You can read more about it f.e. on [this site](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_selectors.asp)

In this case you can use the following code to give them both separate colors:

```
#myList {
    background-color: green;
}

#myList-1 {
    background-color: red;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That is very easy to do. You can either assign them a class name that differs from each other, or you can use their ids like so:

```
#myList{
  background-color:red;
}
#myList-1{
  background-color:blue;
}
```